# SQLite concurrency: the 2nd process doesn't get DB updates

Tags: python, database, sqlite

In order to see if SQLite can be used by 2 processes at the same time, I tried this:

**script1.py** (updating the database every 1 second)

```
import sqlite3, time
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kv (key text, value text)")

for i in range(1000):
    conn.execute('REPLACE INTO kv (key, value) VALUES (?,?)', (1, i))
    conn.commit()
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
```

**script2.py** (querying the database every 1 second)

```
import sqlite3, time
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

while True:
    c.execute('SELECT value FROM kv WHERE key = ?', (1,))
    item = c.fetchone()
    print item
    time.sleep(1)
```

I started `script1.py` and then `script2.py`, and let them running at the same time. I hoped that `script2.py` would know (I don't know how though!) that the DB has been updated, and that it has to reload a part of it. But sadly I get this in `script2.py`:

```
(u'0',)
(u'0',)
(u'0',)
(u'0',)
(u'0',)
(u'0',)
(u'0',)
```

i.e. it doesn't get `script1.py`'s updates.

**Is there a simple way to make this work with SQLite?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with **sqlite3**:
Moved from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409610/share-a-dict-with-multiple-python-scripts) question

#### script1.py

```
import sqlite3, time
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kv (key text unique, value text)")

for i in range(1000):
    conn.execute('REPLACE INTO kv (key, value) VALUES (?,?)', (1, i))
    conn.commit()
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### script2.py

```
import sqlite3, time
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

while True:
    c.execute('SELECT value FROM kv WHERE key = ?', (1,))
    item = c.fetchone()
    print item
    time.sleep(1)
```

#### output

```
python script2.py 
(u'3',)
(u'4',)
(u'5',)
(u'6',)
(u'7',)
```

The problem is that you originally haven't made your **key** [unique](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/)

> When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE
>   algorithm deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint
>   violation prior to inserting or updating the current row and the
>   command continues executing normally.

Without the **key** being unique here's what happening:

```
sqlite3 test.db 
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select * from kv;
1|0
1|1
1|2
1|3
1|4
sqlite> select * from kv;
1|0
1|1
1|2
1|3
1|4
1|5
sqlite> select * from kv;
1|0
1|1
1|2
1|3
1|4
1|5
1|6
1|7
sqlite>
```

And yes, sqlite3 [supports](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) transactions, with a few caveats though. 
So if you also need to support multiple **writers** - multiple **readers** scenario everything may become a bit tricky because of locks contention

Here's a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070369/locking-a-sqlite3-database-in-python-re-asking-for-clarification/12848059#12848059) discussion on the multiple writers case if you need it

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE needs a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint to be able to detect duplicates. (`SELECT MAX(value)...` would work.)

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, could you state the code line? Is `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kv (key text PRIMARY KEY, value text)` correct or `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kv (key text UNIQUE , value text)` or something else? What would be your choice among UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY?